# Jest Angular test NavigationEnd

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-router, ts-jest

Here is my component code that i want to test:

```
allpages: Array<Page> = [
  { name: 'Home', url: '/home' },
];

constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.$routerEvent = this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        let route = event.url !== '/' ? event.url : event.urlAfterRedirects;
        this.currentPage = this.allpages.find(
          (page) => page.url === route
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is my test:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [NavigationBarComponent],
    imports: [MatIconModule, RouterTestingModule],
  }).compileComponents();

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavigationBarComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should set home page as current page', inject([Router], (router: Router) => {
  router.initialNavigation();
  expect(component.currentPage).toEqual({ name: 'Home', url: '/home' });
}));
```

Test fails because component.currentPage = undefined.

I have read that navigation is an async operation, how do i properly should implement the test, or maybe i went absolutely incorrect way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test router events, we need to mock the router service object. In the test session configuration, we will replace events property of router as an Observable object. To have access to the events observable object, we create a separate variable of `ReplaySubject<RouterEvent>.`

```
 const eventSubject = new ReplaySubject<RouterEvent>(1);
```

Crate a router mock

```
const routerMock = {
     events: eventSubject.asObservable(),
 };
```

While using mock object do not use `RouterTestingModule`

Explanation:[Angular 2 Final Release Router Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623722/angular-2-final-release-router-unit-test)

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [NavigationBarComponent],
    imports: [MatIconModule],
    providers: [
        {provide: Router, useValue: routerMock} <-- Override with mock object
    ]

  }).compileComponents();

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavigationBarComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should set home page as current page', () => {
   // simulate the navigation end events
    eventSubject.next(new NavigationEnd(1, '/home', '/urlAfterRedirect'));
    expect(app.currentPage).toEqual({ name: 'Home', url: '/home' });
});
```

[Ref:Approach using Jasmine](https://medium.com/practical-angular-karma-testing/testing-angular-router-events-in-practice-ef1ac517b3ea)
[More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70167177/angular-is-it-possible-to-write-test-case-for-code-inside-constructor)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added the code you provided and now all my tests fail with: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'root')". Seems like the mock config is a bit incorrect

Comment: I found what caused it. The google says that you cannot use the RouterTestingModule along with the routerMock. This will lead to my error. But without RouterTestingModule i get testing warnings that 'Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. How to bypass this?

Comment: `schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]` in ngModule schemas array

Comment: `import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';`

Comment: `beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: [
        {provide: Router, useValue: routerMock}
    ],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  });`